# Help with conversion from SI Units to General Relativity Units

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, si-units, unit-conversion

The Book im reading about general relativity says that energy unit in GR are kg, so until i know the units of energy in the SI are Joules (J)
$$
                                  1 J = 1 kg \frac{m^2}{s^2}
$$
the books says i need to use these convertion rules
$$
1 s = 3 \times 10^{8} m  
$$
and
$$
1 m= \frac{1}{3\times10^8 s}
$$
but if i use the last two equation in the first only i get
$$
1 J = \frac{1kg}{81 \times 10^{32}s^{2}m^{2}}
$$
what im doing wrong?

Comment: use *one* of the equations, not both!

Comment: You have evidently misread the location os *s* in the 3rd equation you write.  Is it consistent with the second?

Answer (score 2):

When doing calculations in general relativity we don't distinguish between matter and energy. Instead we treat them as the same thing related by Einstein's famous equation $E=mc^2$. So if you're trying to turn a mass in $kg$ into an energy in $J$ just multiply it by $c^2$ in SI units i.e. $299792458^2$.

Likewise, if you're trying to trun an energy in $J$ into a mass in $kg$ just divide by $299792458^2$.